# Multiple canonical URLs for same page

Tags: seo, google-search-console, canonical-url, search-results, rel-alternate

I have an existing canonical URL in the form `http://example.com/page1` for a page called `http://example.com/page1.html` and use `.htaccess` to rewrite the URL of anything without an extension so it ends in `.html`

However, I want to create a new page which can be accessed as either `http://example.com/page1` or `http://example.com/page1-alternative-name` (or the .html versions of either).

- Can I add a canonical URL for this alternative name, but have google &  other search engines index it under both names, but recognize both as the same page with the same rank/SEO result, and combined webmaster stats?
- If a canonical URL should not be used will the `.htaccess` access rewrite rule alone by enough to allow search engines to recognize non-duplicate content with alternative names? Is there something I can do to flag this alternative name like `link=alternate`?

Page names and given SEO weight and certain terms/phrases have multiple preferred terms (this is not some kind of keyword stuffing).

So far from reading many answers here I can see multiple canonicals are allowed, but cannot find anything similar to this situation.

Comment: "have google [...] index it under both names" - and which one should be returned in the SERPs? "multiple canonicals are allowed" - multiple _canonicals_ doesn't really make sense. You either have a canonical or you don't.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to have `/primary1` & `/alt1` both indexed with the same content. This will appear to search engines as duplicate pages and have a negative effect on your ranking.

Without fully understanding what you're doing, it sounds like you just want both URLs accessible, so you'd be better off setting the canonical for `/alt1` to point to `/primary1` so that gets the best chance of ranking well. You can then still link to `/alt1` and use it in emails and ad campaigns, but the primary URL `/primary1` will always be canonical.

Comment: so that means only one name will rank well?